# i build heroku app and i an building success but Dynos can't display my code of course i waiting a lot

Tags: heroku

i build heroku app and i an building success
but Dynos can't display my code
of course i waiting a lot

What's wrong?

[heroku error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxAD2.png)

PS C:\Users\PARK\Desktop\DISCORD> git push heroku master
Everything up-to-date

[build success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7evZb.png)